# Secure isolation of two Javascript code bases in the same runtime?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Assume I have two separate Javascript code bases that I am using at the same time in the same runtime. (E.g. two libraries.) I would like to be able to be certain that code base A can do nothing whatsoever to spy on, or interfere with anything that code base B is doing.

I doubt that's possible in plain Javascript, but what about some derivative like some version of TypeScript? I'm also interested in any experimental projects anybody might be aware of that do something like this.

Both/either browser-based runtime and server-side runtime.

Comment: what sort of interference are you anticipating?

Comment: Use a separate runtime if you don't trust A. Or even better don't run A at all if you don't trust it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/caja/docs/about

Comment: Thanks for this link @Bergi, the Google Caja page is describing the problem I'm trying to solve better than I would. Sadly the project is dead.

Comment: I guess it was meant to be superseded by https://github.com/tc39/proposal-realms